How to find out if statistical significant difference exists between 5 treatments over time
Assume I have 5 fields (F1...F5), each one treated (T) in a different manner so that F1=T1, F2=T2, ..., F5=T5. I measure a response variable in each field at different times (t) let's say from 1 to 10 days (t1...t10). What's the correct test to understand if there's a difference between the fields/treatments if I consider my response variable measured over time?
Is it a simple repeated measures ANOVA? a 2-Way Repeated Measures ANOVA with the within groups [Treatment, Time]? If so, how would you set it up? I've tried both Python and SPSS but I fail to organize the data in a proper manner and I generally end up knowing if a significant difference exists between the fields at t1,t2,t3 and so on, but not if there's a significant difference overall between T1...T5.

Looks like a repeated measures ANOVA, since field=treatment.
